# Async controller method displays type name of Task<ActionResult>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, task

I am playing around with ASP.NET MVC5 and RavenDB. I wanted to use Raven's asynchronous API but for the life of me can't get it to work.

My controller (the actual query result is faked since there is no data in the DB)

```cs
public class BooksController : Controller
{
  public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
  {
    var books = this.documentSession.Query<Book>();
    Book book = await books.FirstOrDefaultAsync() ?? 
      new Book { Title = "Programming WCF service", ASIN = "B0043D2DUK" };
    return this.View(book);
  }
}
```

And the view `IndexAsync.cshtml`

```html
@using Hydra.FubuConventions
@model Hydra.Models.Book
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Books Asynchronous";
}
<h2>Books Asynchronous</h2>
@Html.FormBlock(x => x.Title)
@Html.FormBlock(x => x.ASIN)
```

The Web.config

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.html"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It works perfectly fine when I use a synchronous controller method to feed it with a model. But with the asynchronous method it only displays

`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]`

I found plenty of posts here on stackoverflow that indicate that an older version of MVC might be the problem. But I checked the version of the MVC dlls (System.Web.Helpers v3.0.11001.0, System.Web.Mvc v5.0.11001.0 and System.Web.WebPages v3.0.11001.0) in my output folder which seem to be correct.

Any ideas what I am missing?

---

**UPDATE**

I compared the list of loaded assemblies. Other than the obvious differences by assemblies loaded in only one of the projects they were a match. The web.config is identical. I replaced the call to RavenDB with the same test stub that I used in the new project. Still get the type name rather than the view.

Comment: Have you migrated the project from an earlier MVC version? Create a new project and add a scaffolded async controller to assure yourself that async controllers do work. If they don't you are missing packages from your development environment, but I doubt it. You probably have the wrong version configured in `web.config`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos empty project works as expected...

Comment: @SebastianWeber: Since you have a solution that works and one that doesn't, it only remains to find the difference between the two.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Assembly versions look identical. Web.config is the same. I even used the same test stub instead of RavenDB. Any more ideas where I could look?

Comment: Your `web.config` is missing the assembly redirection elements that point to the latest MVC version.

Comment: From what version have you migrated this project? Are you using any IoC container?

Comment: @YK1 Not migrated. It is an MVC 5.0 project created with VS2012. I'm using Unity as IoC container.

Comment: If you use a custom ControllerActionInvoker, you may have to inherit it from `AsyncControllerActionInvoker`.

Comment: @YK1 THAT'S IT! I use a custom `ControllerActionInvoker` that did NOT derive from `AsyncControllerActionInvoker`. Make that comment an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a custom ControllerActionInvoker, you'll have to inherit it from `AsyncControllerActionInvoker`.

Answer (score 1):

You must target .NET 4.5 **and** set `httpRuntime.targetFramework` to `4.5` in your `web.config`.

Comment: Project's Target framework is set to .NET Framework 4.5 (in project properties). And as shown in the web.config above the httpRuntime.targetFramework is also set to 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Your `web.config` lacks the assembly redirection directives found on a new MVC project. I suspect older MVC  assemblies are installed in the GAC and are picked up by your app.

In any case, the behavior is a typical version mismatch. You need to find why the older assemblies are loaded by comparing the differences between your project and a new, clean MVC 5 project.

On a new MVC 5.2 project, the `<runtime>` section in web config contains these assembly redirections:

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

You should copy the redirections from the clean project to your old project and see whether this solves the problem

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But the redirects didn't fix the problem. I'm still on MVC 5.0 with VS2012 btw.

Comment: The clean project proves that you are loading the wrong MVC version somewhere. The specific version numbers I posted are for 5.2. Did you use the redirections found in the clean project? Did you also delete any MVC dlls from your project's folders? You may have copied older versions somewhere and forgot about it. Clean the `bin` folder. You don't need any DLLs there, it will be recreated when you build your project

Comment: The clean project does not have any redirects. I updated all of the nuget packages in my "problem project" (which added a whole host of redirects) but that didn't work either.